# Rendering Multiple jsx with map and contains throws syntax error : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render jsx using `map` and then using `includes` to display a text based on the value present in the list. It throws error saying `"message": "Unexpected token. Did you mean` {'}'}`or`}`. Can someone help me with this

The code that I have tried:

```
  return (
    <>
      {list.length
        ?
          list.map((item, idx) => {
            return (
              <span key={idx}>
                {item}
              </span>
            )}
          {list.includes("Test") && (
            <span key="test">
              Replacement
            </span> )
          }
        )
        : "-"}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `list.includes` inside your `map` function after you closed the curly bracket. I think you wanted something like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      {list.length
        ?
          (<>
           {list.map((item, idx) => {
            return (
              <span key={idx}>
                {item}
              </span>
            )}
          )}
          {list.includes("Test") && (
            <span key="test">
              Replacement
            </span> )
          }
        </>)
        : "-"}
    </>
  );
```